# Automate VoiceOver being controlled by AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, voiceover

I'm trying to find a way to automate the checking of the `Allow VoiceOver to be controlled with AppleScript` option on `VoiceOver Utility.app` so that VoiceOver can be controlled by AppleScript. Specifically for use in GitHub actions macos workflows.

[image: VoiceOver Utility app with the "Allow VoiceOver to be controlled with AppleScript" checkbox highlighted]

From what I can tell, whether this is enabled or not is driven by the presence of a `/private/var/db/Accessibility/.VoiceOverAppleScriptEnabled` file (containing the single character `a` - as determined by digging into `VoiceOver Utility` / `ScreenReaderCore.framework`), but this directory has SIP so writing the file is a no-go (disabling SIP not an option).

It also appears trying to import a `.voprefs` file with the `SCREnableAppleScript` key set to true is simply ignored.

Attempts to UI script the clicking of the checkbox appears to just being doing nothing in  GitHub actions for macos-11 or macos-10.15 envs, and screenshots of the final state look like nothing has happened at all (checkbox remains unchecked, no sign of SecurityAgent popup window etc.). For completeness here's the script I've tried:

```
delay 2

log "Starting AppleScript..."

do shell script "mkdir -p ./screenshots"
do shell script "screencapture ./screenshots/starting.png"

log "Activating VoiceOver Utility..."
tell application "VoiceOver Utility" to activate

delay 1

tell application "System Events"
    repeat while not (exists window 1 of application process "VoiceOver Utility")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    do shell script "screencapture ./screenshots/activated.png"

    log "Ticking checkbox..."

    tell application process "VoiceOver Utility"
        repeat until (exists checkbox 2 of splitter group 1 of window 1)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat

        click checkbox 2 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    end tell

    delay 2

    do shell script "screencapture ./screenshots/checkbox.png"
end tell

log "Quiting VoiceOver Utility..."
tell application "VoiceOver Utility"
  quit
end tell
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: Curiously, I _can_ recreate the AppleScript "doing nothing" behaviour locally if I open `VoiceOver Utility.app` with `sudo`, i.e. `sudo /System/Applications/Utilities/VoiceOver\ Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/VoiceOver\ Utility` - trying to tick the checkbox then does naught! Opening normally locally on Monterey seems to work fine with the AppleScript. Curious whether it's a quirk of the user setup in the virtual env 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleScript control of VoiceOver is now available out of the box for GitHub actions following some collaboration with the maintainers. The checkbox in question is now ticked by default.

Issue: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/4770

PRs:

- https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/pull/4805
- https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/pull/4824